# Routing packets from one interface to another

Tags: ip, routing, ssh-tunneling

## Summary Of The Problem

Here is a routing table on a linux computer:

```
root@computer:~# ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
10.0.0.200 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.100
```

Packets with a destination IP of 1.2.3.5 sent to tun0 on this computer are not being sent out of eth0.

## Long Description Of What I Am Trying To Build

The goal of this project is it give one of my computers (and more of them at a later time) a public IP address. There are two requirements:

- This computer is behind a NAT that I do not control.
- I don't want other computers on my LAN to need to go over the (relatively) slow internet to accesses it.

## Architecture

This is the architecture I am working with: [image]

Computer:

- A: a random computer on the internet that wants to connect to computer F.
- B: has an extra IP (1.2.3.5) I want to route to F through E.
- C: out of my control.
- D: my router, it has a static route: 1.2.3.5 ---> 192.168.1.3
- E: establishes an SSH TUN with B, routes incoming packets destined for  1.2.3.5 to its default gateway D.
- F: a server that I want all other computers (both on my LAN for on the internet) to access by 1.2.4.5

## Setup

IP forwarding was setup on B, E, F with:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

/etc/sysctl.conf was modified in E:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

SSH TUN established on E with:

```
ssh -w 0:0 1.2.3.4
```

tun0 interface brought up on E with:

```
ip link set tun0 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.100/32 peer 10.0.0.200 dev tun0
```

tun0 interface brought up on B with:

```
ip link set tun0 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.200/32 peer 10.0.0.100 dev tun0
```

I can now successfully ping E from B with:

```
ping 10.0.0.100
```

IP 1.2.3.5 removed from interface on B with:
    ifconfig venet0:1 0.0.0.0

route added to B with:
    ip route add 1.2.3.5/32 via 10.0.0.100 dev tun0

IP added to interface on F with:
    ip addr add 1.2.3.5 dev eth0

## Tests

The following command was run on A to test sending packets:

```
netcat -u 1.2.3.5 4444
```

The following commands were run on E to see if packets were being received:

```
root@computer:~$ tcpdump -n -i tun0 port 4444
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
13:48:21.034003 IP 4.3.2.1.44312 > 1.2.3.5.4444: UDP, length 5


root@computer:~$ tcpdump -n -i eth0 port 4444
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:48:21.034061 IP 4.3.2.1.44312 > 1.2.3.5.4444: UDP, length 5
```

The following command was run on E:

```
root@computer:~# netcat -u 1.2.3.5 4444
test
```

With the following command simultaneously run on F:

```
root@computer:~# nc -ul 4444
test
```

## Issue

The problem I am facing is one of the computers (E) is receiving IP packets for a certain IP (1.2.3.5) but not forwarding them to its default gateway.

I believe what I am missing is a command on E that will route incoming packets on the tun0 interface to its default gateway on the eth0 interface.

Does anyone know what command I may be missing?

Comment: Could be that E is rejecting the packets coming in on tun0 with source addresses that don't route back out `tun0`? Make sure that the value of `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/rp_filter` is `0`. Otherwise, some more `tcpdump` results could be helpful: When you try to send packets from A to F (all the way) (1) does E receive them (`tcpdump -n -i tun0 port 4444`)? (2) does E sent them out again (`tcpdump -n -i eth0 port 4444`)?

Comment: Also: do not use `ssh` to build an IP-level tunnel You'll run into the TCP-in-TCP tunnel problem. Use OpenVPN or something like that instead.

Comment: I set up OpenVPN between E and B. That part seems to be working well. Unfortunately my setup continues to have the same issue as before. I found rp_filter was indeed 1 and set it to 0. I posted some tcpdump results. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hmm. Can you reach 1.2.3.5 directly from E? I think I didn't see that in your tests. That would at least prove E follows its default route correctly and the 1.2.3.5/32 static route on D (which you didn't list in the "Setup" section but you mentioned earlier that it was there) are working.

Comment: Yes, E can reach F directly by 1.2.3.5.

Comment: Oddly enough I am now seeing the packet in eth0. Possibility because I modified _sysctl.conf_ instead of _echo 0 >_ to the _rp_filter_. I now have to figure out why the packet is not making it to D. Ill try some more packet captures and see if I can find where they are disappearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing problem was solved by Celada's advise to disable *Reverse Path Filtering* by modifying the file /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

Though I now realize that in order to compete this setup I will also need route returning packets back through E and B to avoid upstream reverse path filtering by my ISP.